# How can i build a windows desktop app using flutter of a module A that belongs to a system z?

Tags: flutter, dart, building

Using flutter, i have a module A, that is part of a bigger system Z. Module A draws it's parameters and configurations from the users from system Z. Normally, the users create the module A according to their preferences, and once completed, it's ready to use. Once that instance of the module A has been created is there a way to build a windows desktop app of that Module A in specific?

From what i have searched, the build windows release command works for the entire project, i don't need that, i need it just for the module itself, while having all of it's configurations drawn from the system Z once created, and when the users press a 'download' button in that module configuration screen.